# Given a list of template argument values, how can I force instantiations of a template class for all values in the list?

Tags: c++

I have a case like this:

```cpp
template <typename T> struct foo {};

template <typename ... T> struct type_list { };

using list_type = type_list<int, float, char>;
```

In a particular translation unit, I would like to explicitly instantiate `foo` for all of the types in `list_type`, which I could do manually by placing this in the source file:

```cpp
template class foo<int>;
template class foo<float>;
template class foo<char>;
```

However, I would like to do this for any list of types that I might have in `list_type`. Is there a way to expand the parameter pack in `list_type` to force instantiation of `foo` for each of its types? C++11-only solutions are ideal, but if something like C++17 is needed, then so be it.

Comment: There is nothing in the language allowing automation of explicit instantiations unfortunately. Best solution would be using a macro from which the type and the instantiations are derived.

Comment: Implicit instantiation can be done, but it doesn't solve your issue...

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve here. No, not the problem with instantiating templates like that, but the real problem to which you believe the solution involves instantiating templates like that, so that's what you're asking about. Perhaps if the real problem is described then a different solution will be possible.

Comment: I have a template declared in a public header, but defined in a source file not included from said header. The template is valid for a certain set of parameters, and I would like to explicitly instantiate them in one translation unit so they are only instantiated once (they are expensive to compile). For other reasons, I already have a type that lists all of the valid template arguments, hence my desire for a method to automatically instantiate the template for the types in that list. I am trying to avoid the use of macros and to keep the code DRY.

Comment: In C++ templates really like to be defined wherever they're referenced. Explicit instantiation is part of the language, but is sort of like an ugly duckling. In analogous situations, where C++ naturally doesn't do 100% of the job, in the past I resorted to external scripting that I integrated into the build system. Here, I would define the valid "set of parameters" in one place, and have a build script robo-generate a `.cpp` that enumerates the template declarations, and a header file with the corresponding type list declaration.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in providing a template definition in .cpp file if you can explicitly list all the valid template instantiations. I do it all the time!

Comment: @Jarod42: indeed, I have tried generating implicit instantiations by initializing a global variable using an IILE that contains code that constructs an object of all of the classes in question. It *almost* works, but the approaches I’ve tried all have failed to properly instantiate all of the class members (namely, the constructor, which I’m guessing is being inlined).

Comment: @JasonR It is easy to force implicit instantiation in the way that you describe, but that's not at all sufficient for what you want. Explicit instantiation and implicit instantiation behave very differently. Implicit instantiation in one translation unit is not enough to satisfy ODR for uses in other translation units. You must use individual explicit instantiation definitions for each specialization to get the intended behavior. There is unfortunately no other way.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit instantiations are written as declarations and each explicit instantiation declaration can only specify one single specialization to explicitly instantiate. They can also only appear at namespace scope, so not inside another template definition.

Nothing in the language, except token replacement via the preprocessor, is able to generate multiple declarations without writing every single one explicitly.

So, the best you can do is write a macro that both declares the type and the explicit instantiations.

Hopefully C++ will at some point get reflection capabilities and as a (probably later) part of it the ability to introduce declarations based on these reflections in an automatised way during compilation. But currently nothing for that exists, only preprocessor macros or external code generation.